# make x ERR not found: make-.env running make mocked on Windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, makefile, mocking, pact

I am trying to run this locally on my Windows 10 machine:
*https://github.com/pactflow/example-consumer-cypress*

I have installed npm on the root directory then run `make mocked`.
However, I get the following error message:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined
(node:9928) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9928) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
make × ERR  not found: make-.env
```

I tried this command as well and same error: `make mocked --debug --unhandled-rejections=strict`

I also entered a dummy `.env` and `make-.env` files on the root directory but same error.
Furthermore, the `Makefile` exists on the root directory as I just downloaded the repo to my local machine.

For some reason, I am unable to find the exact error via Stackoverflow or Google. Unsure if this is related to my Windows machine, the Pact tool I am trying to configure, or on the make package itself as I am quite unfamiliar with mocking.

I also reached out to the Pact team and they mentioned that it should work locally and it might be related to windows path length issues but the solution didn't work either: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-node/blob/master/README.md#enable-long-paths

Comment: `I tried this command as well and same error:` I'm surprised by that. Make doesn't complain about the `--unhandled-rejections` option? It's not an option supported by Make, so I would expect that to cause a different error.

Comment: As per the error above, it suggested to include that CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections` but weird that its still the same error.

Comment: Also, on some of the JS files in the repo (ProductPage.js & App.js), I commented out the `.catch` function but still same error.